# ошибка Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyautogui

библиотека pyautogui не хочет нормально работать и выдает ошибки

```
import pyautogui
import time
i = 1
while i < 1000:
    i = i + 1
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.moveTo(453, 1012)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.write('Hello world!', interval=0.1)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

вот весь код ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ПК\Desktop\spam.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 221, in <module>
    locateOnWindow.__doc__ = pyscreeze.locateOnWindow.__doc__
AttributeError: module 'pyscreeze' has no attribute 'locateOnWindow'
```

код писался в висуал студио ,а в качестве компилятора использовал Thonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите модули

```
pyscreeze
pymsgbox
pytweening
```

Если не помогло возможно у вас не верная версия python. Используйте 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло [это решение](https://qna.habr.com/q/1019206)

Удалите прошлый PyAutoGUI:

```
pip uninstall PyAutoGUI
```

И поставьте предыдущую версию:

```
pip install PyAutoGUI==0.9.52
```